# Trying to use devcontainers with a docker compose file immediately fails

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use devcontainers with docker compose. I get this error immediately:

```
Command 'Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container' resulted in an error (Command failed: /private/var/folders/vw/m_7gmll54yb0cnfp687dxh740000gq/T/AppTranslocation/1485CA8A-FFAA-4796-BA55-5928911F8CB3/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /Users/me/myfolder/myproject --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/me/myfolder/myproject/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --include-merged-configuration --mount-workspace-git-root true)
```

Where do I even go to see logs?

I confirmed my compose file works fine when I run it with the regular `docker compose` command.

This is my dev container config:

```
{
"name": "Python 3",
"dockerComposeFile": [
    "../docker-compose.yml"
],
"service": "devcontainer_testenv",
"workspaceFolder": "/app",
"shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
// Configure tool-specific properties.
"customizations": {
    // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
    "vscode": {
        // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
        "settings": {
            "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
                "bash": {
                    "path": "/bin/bash"
                }
            },
            "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
            "python.languageServer": "Default",
            "python.linting.enabled": true,
            "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
            "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/autopep8",
            "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
            "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/yapf",
            "python.linting.banditPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/bandit",
            "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
            "python.linting.mypyPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/mypy",
            "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pycodestyle",
            "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pydocstyle",
            "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pylint"
        },
        // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
        "extensions": [
            "ms-python.python",
            "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I feel totally helpless, where do I see an error log? It pops this error in less than a second when I try to run `Dev Containers: Reopen and Rebuild`.

I have "Use Docker Compose V2" enabled as well.